# Rust TCP Socket Pooling

Tags: sockets, rust, connection-pooling, rust-tokio

I'm writing a client library for a custom TCP-based protocol. I'd like the library to easily permit users to make requests on multiple threads, which is the reason for my question. My library is intended to replace a slow, Python-based implementation which I've identified as a bottleneck in our pipeline, so request throughput is crucial here. So far, I've used `tokio`'s networking facilities so that, once I've got concurrent sockets, I'll be able to execute requests in parallel. After the application opens a socket, the protocol allows it to re-use the connection for subsequent requests.

When a session begins, the applications sends an initial request and receives an authorization token in return, which it must include with future requests. Requests are frequent and small but irregular in their contents, so I'd like to pool my TCP sockets, like (I imagine) a web browser does to support the `keep-alive` mechanism. I very much want to avoid having each request spin up a new socket -- even though it could re-use the existing authorization token -- because of the delays associated with the TCP's three-way handshake and slow start.

The classic solution to this problem is a connection pool, like you'd use in a web application to connect to a database. The trouble is, I haven't been able to find a good connection pool for sockets, and I'd prefer to avoid introducing the complexity of one I write myself. There's `r2d2` (see [here](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2)), for instance, but that only supports database connections. Meanwhile, `tk_pool` ([here](https://docs.rs/tk-pool/0.5.3/tk_pool/)) hasn't been updated in two years, which is not encouraging.

This feels like a common task, so I'm surprised I haven't yet found a simple way to do this. I'm new to Rust's async/await features and `tokio`, so I may well be missing something essential. Here's the question, simply:

**How can I distribute many bits of IO across several sockets, each connected to the same host?** Put another way, how can I have a pool of workers take temporary ownership of (or gain a mutable reference to) the first available of a set of equivalent resources?

I'm open to all manner of suggestions, but to avoid making this question opinion based, I think the central question is one of fact: What is the idiomatic, async Rust way to do connection pooling?

Thanks!

---

Here's some pseudo-code that outlines how I'm imagining my code would look, once I've identified the right way to do this:

```
 
struct Session {
    pool: ConnectionPool<tokio::net::TcpStream>,
    // authorization token, etc.
}

impl Session {
    async fn make_request(&mut self, parameters...) -> Result<Response, Error> {
         let sock = self.pool.borrow_socket(); // probably requires &mut self. Won't be able to distribute the Session object if it requires mutable references. Will I need to use Cell?
         sock.write(format!("request: {}", parameters)).await?;
         let results = sock.read().await?;
         
         Ok(parse(results)?)

         // sock is dropped, which returns it to the pool; alternatively, maybe you've got to call, e.g., sock.release().
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking `&mut self` would be a problem indeed. You can see that r2d2 [uses a Vec behind a Mutex](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2/blob/c83f94b0283a6650c21bfb56448e4db3e9bbe6df/src/lib.rs#L168-L183) to store the connections to work around this.

Comment: I do not think there is something in r2d2 that inherently ties it to *database* connections. Check out also [bb8](https://github.com/khuey/bb8), the async alternative to r2d2.